# Powershell history isn't persistent anymore

Tags: powershell, windows-11, command-history

Powershell stopped using its persistent history (Windows 11). When I start a new Powershell instance commands from previous sessions don't show up. Once I use commands in the new session for the first time they can be recalled via F8/arrows etc.

**What I checked/found out so far:**

- Checking the history file `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt` I noticed commands do not get saved there (anymore).
- Once I enter the command `(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath` (which returns the path I mentioned in my previous bullet point) everything works fine again. Commands already saved there are accessible again via F8 etc. and new commands get saved into the history file again as well.
- Using `powershell -noexit Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySavePath "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt"` to start powershell via a script works as well.

I haven't found out exactly why Powershell isn't using the history file by default anymore. As far as I remember it used to work earlier and I'm not sure why it stopped working. But it was already some time ago judging by the content of the history file.

Any idea how I can get it working again **without** a workaround that has to be applied on every startup (like typing in the "history save command" manually or using a "parameter to start it")?

**Addition 1:**

These commands give the following output (note: after using any of them the history works fine again, commands get saved to history and the full can be recalled except for the first command that has been used and "reactivated" the history)

```
PS C:\> (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySaveStyle
SaveIncrementally
PS C:\> (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistoryNoDuplicates
True
PS C:\> (Get-PSReadlineOption).MaximumHistoryCount
4096
```

**Addition 2:**

`$PROFILE` gives me the following output (the command does not affect the history's behavior). Note: the files listed do not exist within the indicated directories:

```
PS C:\> $PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty


   TypeName: System.String

Name                   MemberType   Definition
----                   ----------   ----------
AllUsersAllHosts       NoteProperty string AllUsersAllHosts=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    NoteProperty string AllUsersCurrentHost=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    NoteProperty string CurrentUserAllHosts=C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost NoteProperty string CurrentUserCurrentHost=C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

**Addition 3 - including a workaround:**

Seems the PSReadLine module isn't loading. Using `Import-Module PSReadLine` makes the history work properly. As a workaround, I put the command into the PS profile file, so it gets executed automatically **which fixes the problem but not the cause**. This is probably also the reason why the history starts working once a command relating to the modulus is used, I assume PowerShell loads the module by itself.

**Addition 4:**

The problem is specific to the user profile. In a new user profile, the history works fine. Standard checks using `sfc`, `dism` and `chkdsk` didn't yield any results.

Comment: What does `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySaveStyle` , `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistoryNoDuplicates` , and `(Get-PSReadlineOption).MaximumHistoryCount` reveal?  If necessary, you can use `Set-PSReadLineOption` to change these options.

Comment: Maybe look over some configs per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2 and values may be set there changing it at every session, etc. per the profile configs. Or see about putting applicable `Set-PSReadLineOption` in the profile. Maybe that sort of workaround is what is causing you to need a workaround where it's settings it some other way each session, etc.

Comment: @leeharvey1 I added the output of the commands to my question, seems to be ok

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I used `$PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty`, curiously the files do not exist (see addition 2 to the question), in neither scenario (when its working/not working). Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Albin - the lack of a profile file is not part of the problem. as with the other core modules, the PSReadLine stuff is loaded automatically. i dunno how that is done, tho. ///// however, you may want to add such a file with a command to activate that module ... until you find out why it aint loading automatically.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok, my initial thought was the profile file should exist by default and might cause problems if it's missing. good idea using it as a workaround to load the module, works fine. I used `Import-Module PSReadLine` - found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474973/windows-powershell-persistent-history)

Comment: @Albin - yes, the profile files are NOT created by default. you - or your other apps - need to make them as needed. i am glad that you got things working ... and i wish you luck getting the actual problem fixed ... [*grin*]

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle no corruption in the system files, the windows image, or the file system. And yes, the problem is user profile specific, good point! I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my question, as a workaround I currently use `Import-Module PSReadLine` in my profile file, which I access via `notepad $PROFILE`. Since the problem only exists for my profile, this does the trick for my user without affecting any other user.

Although this does not resolve the problem - for now it fixes all my current issues.